# How to Grammatically Discern These?

Tags: questions, syntax

In this, I aim to discern (parse[?]) these, grammatically, and have them complete. May these seem grammatically discerned, properly?

> She (subject, argument) did (auxiliary verb) not (auxiliary adverb) go (verb).

I aim to think of this, as a complete interrogative.

> Did (auxiliary verb) she (subject, argument) not (auxiliary adverb) go (verb)?
>
> Did (auxiliary verb) not (auxiliary adverb) she (subject, argument) go (verb)?
>
> Did (auxiliary adverb) she (subject, argument) go (verb) not (auxiliary adverb)?

May these seem discerned grammatically properly?

> Did (auxiliary adverb) she (subject, argument) go (verb) not (auxiliary adverb)?

And, may this additionally seem syntactically proper?

Comment: *Did not she go?* is ungrammatical **except** in its contracted form *Didn't she go?*. The sentence *Did she go not?* is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1):

Your assertion

> **She did not go**

would be used to answer the question

> Did she **not** go?

Your alternative

> Did **not** she go?

sounds old and **archaic**

> Did she go **not**?

is grammatically incorrect and not said amoung native speakers.

A simpler and more modern form of the question would be

> Did she go **or not**?

to ask if **she** went some place

Comment: So, *“Did she not go”?* works and seems grammatical, and complete? *“Did not she go”?* seems grammatical, and complete, and old and archaic? And, may you not use an adverb after a verb?

Comment: Yes, Yes (sounds like Yoda or olde English); and Yes you may: **she walked softly**

Comment: Excellent. So, I guess, you state yes, to all. I may not get if you state you may use an adverb after a verb, and cannot use that third one?

Comment: No, no, I may not get if you state you may use an adverb after a verb, and cannot use that, I guess, fourth thing I inquired about?

Comment: @saySay You've lost me. fourth thing? 1) grammatical and complete; 2) old and archaic;  3) adverb after a verb; all are yes.

Comment: I may not get if you state you may use an adverb after a verb, and cannot use that fourth thing I inquired about, in, I guess, that original inquiry.